# Can oscillating multi-tools be used for fitting pattress boxes

Tags: tools, brick, powertools

I have a bunch of pattress boxes to fit for light switches and plug sockets and was wondering if my oscillating multi-tool could be of any use.

I have a Bosch PMF 180 E Multi. Can this be used to cut the outside edges for a pattress box in a brick wall?

If it can then what attachment should I use... there are so many!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bosch lists a segmented blade HM-RIFF that it says will cut grooves in porous cement, small cutouts in soft wall tile. I guess four grooves would make a cutout. A lot will depend on the thickness of the brick,.Are you looking to cut thru a brick veneer or the entire thickness of a conventional redbrick? I would try to get a similar material to practice or trial cut.  The width of the blade looks a little wide to cut the short sides. You may be able to make a series of long cuts then chip out the segments.

Comment: I gave it a go with this attachment and it worked pretty well... definitely came out neater than previous attempts